# accessing result array in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following happening in my model:

```
public function load_user_menu($username)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('menu');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

and the following in my controller:

```
public function index()
    {     
        /*If user previously logged in and not logged out, username remains in session.
            load username and load profile data. 
        */
        //check if user logged in or not
        if(($this->session->userdata('username')!=""))
        {
            //load data from model
            $profile = array();
            $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
            $result = $this->profileModel->user_profile($username);
             foreach($result as &$value)
              {
                  $profile['userdetails'] = $value;
              }
            $this->load->view('profile', $profile);
        }else{
            //redirect to login function
            $this->login();
        }
    }
```

but I am getting errors on profile view. I am sure I am accessing them wrong because I am doing this on view:

```
<? echo $userdetails['profilepic']; ?>
```

and nothing is showing  but this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/profile.php
>
> Line Number: 60

which am certain because of the wrong accessing. How can I access the details based on the above?

Comment: Where is `$userdetails['profilepic'];` in your code? The error says there is nothing to get from that variable, defiantly there isn't anything fetched into `$userdetails['profilepic'];`.

Comment: Well what code is on the line that the error mentions?

Answer (score 3):

assumming you have `profilepic` inside userdetails and seeing the error you are trying to get he property of nonobject that means

```
 <? echo $userdetails['profilepic']; ?>
```

should be

```
 <? echo $userdetails->profilepic; ?>
```

since you are taking you result as object and not array

```
return $query->result();
```

or you change this to

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

`$query->result();` produces an object;  `$query->result_array();` gives you an array

either is fine, depending on your needs

Comment: I guess we don't need comments and edits when two people are typing at the same time; happens alot

Answer (score 0):

-There is no need of foreach loop in your controller as

```
$result = $this->profileModel->user_profile($username);
             foreach($result as &$value)
              {
                  $profile['userdetails'] = $value;
              }
```

-Try this instead.

```
$profile['userdetails'] = $this->profileModel->user_profile($username);
```

-To Access in View,use this as

```
echo $userdetails->profilepic;
```

Answer (score -1):

just try this on your view page

```
<? echo $profilepic; ?>
```